# Bring back tab cycling with mouse wheel

Tags: gtk, mouse-wheel

I use gmusicbrowser, which uses GTK. I used to be able to cycle through tabs in the interface using my mouse wheel. This worked in 18.04, and now in 20.04 it does not.

With QT apps, like QownNotes, I can still cycle in this way. Is there a tweak or extension or dconf command I can use to get this functionality back for GTK?

Comment: It is maybe caused "feature" in [Gtk](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/234). How did you installed gmusicbrowser? I do not see it in 20.04 LTS repository, only [in 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gmusicbrowser).